# String split to javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object, split

I have string coming from the server:

```
//A
123|155-244
```

- The first numbers always means 'Red'
- Numbers after `|` always means 'Green'
- Numbers after `-`always means 'Blue'

The issue here is that Green and Blue can come back in either order:

```
//B
123-244|155
```

Or they can be missing entirely:

```
//C
123|155
```

I need a function that returns one array/object to make things easy:

```
//A
var result = {red:"123", green:"155", blue:"244"}

//B
var result = {red:"123", green:"155", blue:"244"}

//C
var result = {red:"123", green:"155", blue:"0"}
```

I've tried two functions, one to get Green and the other Blue, but I realized that doesn't work properly depending on the order they appear in the string.

```
var getGreen = function(myvar){
    return myvar.split('-'); 
};
var getBlue = function(myvar){
    return myvar.split('|'); 
};
```

Doing this sometimes causes my object to look like this:

```
var result = {red:"123", green:"155", blue:"244|155"}
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: David Bm, can we assume there is *always* a value for red?

Comment: Yes, red always come ... blue and green may not come

Comment: Do you want numbers or number strings?

Comment: Are the integers always three digits long? How are smaller values represented?

Comment: i don't mind if they are numbers or strings and the maximum length of the number is 3, it can be lower

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need for regexes:

```js
parse = function(s) {
    return {
        red:   parseInt('+' + s, 10) || 0,
        green: parseInt(s.split('|')[1], 10) || 0,
        blue:  parseInt(s.split('-')[1], 10) || 0,
    };
};

//

test = [
    '123',
    '222|333-444',
    '55-66|77',
    '123|456',
    '123-456',
    '|123-456',
    '-123|456',
    '010|020-030',
  
];
  
test.map(parse).forEach(r => 
   document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(r) + '</pre>'));
```

This uses the fact that `parseInt` stops at the first non-parseable character and returns a falsy value when given garbage. The `'+' + s` hack is to invalidate the leading dash (which otherwise would be mistaken for the minus sign).

Comment: this looks clean... can regex turn something wrong ?

Comment: @DavidBm: regexes are fine, but it's shooting sparrows with cannons in this case.

Comment: Since we don't know whether numbers below 100 might have leading zeroes, I'd recommend to always pass the radix `10` to `parseInt`.

Comment: what does the last 2 argument for ``Stringify()`` mean?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: replacer func and indent, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 10):

You are probably best using a [`Regexp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to match this - one for each section of the string.

[`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) each Regex and the match will be stored in index 1 of the resulting array. If there is no match, then `null` is returned from `exec()`, so use a dummy array of `[null, 0]` simplify things.

Although not a requirement, this also works if there is no red value.

```js
function getRGB() {
  var reRed = /^([0-9]+)/; // start of string (^) then match 1+ numbers
  var reGreen = /\|([0-9]+)/; // a "|" then match 1+ numbers
  var reBlue = /-([0-9]+)/;  // a "-" then match 1+ numbers

  return {
    red: (reRed.exec(input) || [null, 0])[1],
    green: (reGreen.exec(input) || [null, 0])[1],
    blue: (reBlue.exec(input) || [null, 0])[1]
  };
}

// RGB
var input = '123|155-244';
console.log(input, getRGB(input));

// RBG
var input = '123-244|155';
console.log(input, getRGB(input));

// RB
input = '123-244';
console.log(input, getRGB(input));

// BG
var input = '-244|155';
console.log(input, getRGB(input));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with RegEx.

```js
var str = '123|155-244';

var result = {
    red: (str.match(/^\d+/) || [0])[0], // Get first digits or zero
    green: (str.match(/\|(\d+)/) || [0, 0])[1], // Get digits after `|` or zero
    blue: (str.match(/-(\d+)/) || [0, 0])[1] // Get digits after `-` or zero
};

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

---

**Original answer**

Misunderstood that `-` and `|` are interchangeable, but the sequence of colors will be fixed as Red, Green and then Blue.

<strike>You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with regex.</strike>

```js
var str = '123|155-244';
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var result = {};

var arr = str.split(/\||-/g);
arr.forEach((e, i) => result[colors[i]] = arr[i]);

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**Regex Explanation:**

The simple regex `\||-` will split the string by pipe `|` or `-`.

**Another live demo:**

```js
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var str = this.value;
  var result = {};

  var arr = str.split(/\||-/g);
  arr.forEach((e, i) => result[colors[i]] = arr[i]);
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="input" />

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: thanks for the anwer, but i need the object to have the three colors on the result, also if the blue is 0

Comment: Doesn;t work for blue/green being reversed - `123-244|155`

Comment: @Rhumborl Right. I thought `|` and `-` are interchangable, please check update.

Answer (score 3):

You says first number always red so

```
myString = "123-155|244";
red = "0";
green = "0";
blue = "0";
red = mysString.substring(0,3);
if(myString.indexOf("|")!=-1)
{
  green = mystring.substring(myString.indexOf("|")+1,myString.indexOf("|")+4);
}
if(myString.indexOf("-")!=-1)
{
  blue = mystring.substring(myString.indexOf("-")+1,myString.indexOf("-")+4);
}
console.log(red+green+blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.match(regex)`:

```js
var str = "123|155-244",  // <--------the string
  arr = str.match(/(\d{3})+/g), // <----creates array out of str
  obj = {
    red: arr[0], // put first one as red value
    green: arr[1], // second one as green value
    blue: arr.length == 3 ? arr[2] : "000" // as per length of array put blue value 
  };

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: No, the color is not determined by the position of the number but by the character preceding it.

Answer (score 2):

may be this is what you want and write some else condition any how you want

```
var color = {red:null,blue:null,green:null};
var s ="123-244|155";
var blue_index = s.indexOf("|") ;
var green_index = s.indexOf("-") ;
if(blue_index>green_index){
    color.blue = s.split("|")[1];
    s = s.split("|")[0];
}else{
    color.green = s.split("-")[1];
    s = s.split("|")[0];
}
if(s.indexOf("|") > -1){
    color.blue =  s.split("|")[1];
    color.red  =   s.split("|")[0];
}   
if(s.indexOf("-") > -1){
    color.green =  s.split("-")[1];
    color.red  =   s.split("-")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, in end tried testing with all 3 conditions-

```
function rgbFun(a){
    //Define object either way
    //rgb = {'red':0,'blue':0,'green':0}; 
    rgb = {};
    var r = a.substr(0,3),
        b = a.splitOnLast('-')[1], //will check the last splitted value of blue
        g = a.splitOnLast('|')[1]; //will check the last splitted value of green
    rgb.red = r;
    if(b){
        rgb.blue = b.substr(1,3);
    }else{
        rgb.blue = 0;
    }
    if(g){
        rgb.green = g.substr(1,3);
    }else{
        rgb.green = 0;
    }
    return rgb;
}
rgbFun(CaseA);
//Result - {red: "123", blue: "244", green: "155"}
rgbFun(CaseB);
//Result - {red: "123", blue: "244", green: "155"}
rgbFun(CaseC);
//Result - {red: "123", blue: 0, green: "155"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code 
HTML :-

```
<h1 id="red">Red</h1>
<h1 id="green">Green</h1>
<h1 id="blue">Blue</h1>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

JavaScript:-

```
 var myvar="123-244|155";
 var getGreen = myvar.split('-');
var getBlue = getGreen[1].split('|');
function change(){
red.innerHTML+=" ="+getGreen[0];
blue.innerHTML+=" ="+getBlue[0];
green.innerHTML+=" ="+getBlue[1];
}
```